# curljs "Error: fetchText() failed. status: Not Found" when using cjsm11

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, browserify, curljs

I can't quite figure out why I keep on getting this error when trying to test my backbone views with curljs & mocha. They're built with browserify so I'm using commonjs modules.

I created a gist to replicate the issue: https://gist.github.com/aesthaddicts/8925413 – I added a `bower.json` so used modules can be installed by issuing `bower install`.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to test the modules?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I updated the gist, the old error could be resolved

Comment: I don't see what was built with browserify...

Comment: The gist leaves all of the browserify out, I load the modules directly before compiling them. Browserify is the reason why they use the commonjs module definition.

Comment: Nevermind, I opened an issue on github and got some help there. the current version of the gist works, if anyone who's interested.

Comment: Thanks for updating the gist, aesthaddicts! :)